# How to send json data created by nextjs api to a new route?

Tags: json, next.js, api-design, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am a complete web development noob and I am also a bit new to Javascript.
I am trying to make a quizlet style website where users can input the subjects and specific topic they're not very good at and then they get practice questions back rendered in a flashcard.js file I have.

For this I wrote an api in nextjs that generates these practise questions, I know the api works because I see it print out these questions, however I can't figure out how to parse the data into the flashcard.js file.

This is what my handler in my api looks like:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';


export default async function handler(req, res) {

    const { subject, topic, exam_board, qualification } = req.body;

    const questions = await generateQuestions(subject, exam_board, qualification, topic);

    console.log(questions);
    console.log()
  

    res.status(200).json({ questions });
     }
}
```

I would like to try using useRouter but I can't use it within the handler so sort of open to any ideas.

I have been stuck on this for months so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is store the results in a `state`.

You will need to import `useState` from React.

```js
import { useState } from 'React';
```

And declare your state like this.

```js
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState(<default-state-value>);
```

Then pass it as a prop to the flashcard.js component.
You will need to import the component.

```js
import FlashCard from '<path-to-flashcard.js>'
```

Then call that component and pass `questions` state as a prop

```
<FlashCard questionsProp={questions} />
```

And inside that component you can use conditional rendering so that when your state is loaded with the data, then it will get updated in the UI.